# How can I access a .local url for a virtual ubuntu server installation?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, virtual-machines, virtualbox, link-local

I recently installed ubuntu server on a virtualbox virtual machine. I tried to connect it using `<host name>.local` but it didn't work? How can I access it from a url but not an IP?

(I do not want answers saying to modify /etc/hosts)

Comment: If you don't want to modify your `/etc/hosts`, which is easiest and most direct solution for your question, then install `bind`, create `.local` DNS zone and and configure `A` type DNS record for your virtual server. You may even configure bind and your VM to update this record dynamically...

Comment: @SergeyNudnov How can I install it?

Comment: There are many manuals available. [This](https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/06/ubuntu-1804-bind-en/), [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04), [this](http://www.servermom.org/how-to-install-and-setup-bind9-on-ubuntu-server/). Unfortunately, I have no time to create a proper answer...